# ggplotly: rename tooltip on hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

[image]

I have a plotly chart as above. Reusable code as below.

```
plotly::ggplotly(ggplot(dplyr::as_tibble(rnorm(1000)), aes(value)) + stat_ecdf(geom = 'line'))
```

I want to rename and format the tooltip on hovering.
For example, x-axis or 'value' (in the chart) can be 'Unit Price in ฿' while the y-axis is the Cumul Distribution.

So when I hover on the line, I want to be able to see something like below

> Cumul Distribution: 78.2%
>
> Unit Price : ฿0.81

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way.

```
library(plotly)
library(scales) # for the number() function

gg <- ggplot(dplyr::as_tibble(rnorm(1000)), aes(value)) + 
  stat_ecdf(geom = 'line')

ggly <- ggplotly(gg)

text_x <- number(
  ggly$x$data[[1]]$x,
  prefix = "Unit Price: $",
  accuracy = 0.01
)

text_y <- number(
  ggly$x$data[[1]]$y,
  scale = 100,
  accuracy = 0.1,
  prefix = "Cumul. distribution: ",
  suffix = "%"
)

ggly %>%
  style(text = paste0(text_x, "</br></br>", text_y), traces = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stephane, any good resources on where can I learn more about how to style the tooltip? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can you plotly package. Here is an article which tells you how to add a custom tooltip [Plotly](https://www.r-bloggers.com/interactive-ggplot-with-tooltip-using-plotly/)

Hmm, changing aes seems to be the only way we can modify the labels and it doesn't support exactly what you want right now

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using the plotly package as you can see from the code above. The problem I have is with the tooltip.

Comment: My bad I thought you were using ggplot